# Dynamically creating a MessageHub feed trigger via openwhisk npm

Tags: openwhisk, ibm-cloud-functions

Trying to create a MessageHub trigger via the openwhisk Node.js module.  THe trigger gets created but is listed as CustomTrigger and not associated with a message hub feed.

```
const fs = require('file-system');
const openwhisk = require('openwhisk');
let options = { apihost: 'openwhisk.ng.bluemix.net', api_key: 'xxxx',namespace: 'my_dev'};

var ow = openwhisk(options);


let trigoptions = {
      name: 'test-api-trigger',
      annotations: [
         { 
           key: 'feed',
           value: '/my_dev/MyOrg_my-message-hub_my-message-hub-credentials/messageHubFeed'
         }
       ],
       isJSONData : true,
       topic :  'my-events',
       namespace: 'my_dev'
  };

  ow.triggers.create( trigoptions )
     .then( trigger => { console.log(trigger); })
     .catch( err => { console.log(err);});
```

Answer (score 2):

Creating triggers feeds using the SDK requires a separate feed creation operation. This is handled automatically by the CLI. When using the client library, an extra manual step is needed.

Here's a re-worked example from your code...

```
const ow = openwhisk(options);

const feedname = '/user@email.com_dev/Bluemix_Message Hub-ir_Credentials-1/messageHubFeed'

const trigoptions = {
  name: 'sample-api-trigger',
  annotations: [
    { 
      key: 'feed',
      value: feedname
    }
  ]
};

const feedparams = {
  isJSONData: true,
  topic:  'mytopic'
}

ow.triggers.create( trigoptions )
  .then( trigger => { 
    console.log(trigger);

    return ow.feeds.create({name: feedname, trigger: trigoptions.name, params: feedparams}).then(package => {
      console.log('trigger feed created', package)
    }).catch(err => {
      console.error('failed to create trigger feed', err)
    })
  })
  .catch( err => { console.log(err);});
```

*There is an [outstanding issue](https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk-client-js/issues/128) that trigger annotations (used to store feed reference) cannot be created using the JavaScript SDK.*